# How do I write an rspec 3.1 test for this

Tags: ruby, rspec

How do I write a rspec test for the following.

the value that gets passed in is this...
90A14F    1.4

```
  def classname
    def init
      @input_colors = Array.new
    end
    def speak
      puts "enter your line of color values"
      result = STDIN.gets.chomp
      new_result = result.gsub!(/([\s])+/,':')
      @input_colors << new_result
    end
  end
```

How do I write an rspec 3.1 test for this speak method that test if gets.chomp is...90A14F    1.4

They will get an instance var @input_colors == ["90A14F:1.4"]

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your example. I would change and fix it to something like this:

```
class ColorReader            # with `class` and an upcase class name
  def initialize             # not `init`
    @colors = []             # the use of `Array.new` is uncommon
  end

  def read
    puts "enter your line of color values"
    result = STDIN.gets.chomp
    new_result = result.gsub!(/([\s])+/,':')
    @colors << new_result
  end
end
```

Then a test could look like this:

```
describe ColorReader do
  describe '#read' do
    let(:input) { "90A14F 1.4\n" }

    subject(:color_reader) { ColorReader.new }

    before do
      allow(color_reader).to receive(:puts).and_return(nil)
      allow(STDIN).to receive(:gets).and_return(input)
    end

    it 'writes to the console' do
      color_reader.read
      expect(color_reader).to have_received(:puts).
        with("enter your line of color values").once
    end

    it 'reads from STDIN' do
      color_reader.read
      expect(STDIN).to have_received(:gets).once
    end

    it 'returns the sanitized input' do
      expect(color_reader.read).to eq(['90A14F:1.4'])
    end
  end
end
```

Btw. I would prefer to explicitly test the new value of the `@colors` array (perhaps with `attr_reader :colors`) and not the implizit return value of the `read` method. If you have a reader for the `@colors` then the last spec can be changed to:

```
it 'adds the sanitized input to `colors`' do
  expect { 
    color_reader.read 
  }.to change { color_reader.colors }.from([]).to(['90A14F:1.4'])
end
```